# Linux kernel Development-How 'incomplete feature's'code is removed during release candidate prior to production release

Tags: git, version-control, linux-kernel

How 'incomplete feature's'code is removed during release candidate prior to production release? Say if some feature is accepted by kernel development committee and code got merged during merge window. But there is bug in this feature. Which was not got resolved during release candidate.

Comment: What's your branch structure of the git repo?

Answer (score 0):

Kernel goes through development cycles. When a release is made, first come release canditates: *-rcN, e.g. 4.14.0-rc5. They contain bug fixes. Then a final release (non-rc) is made, e.g. 4.14. Further patches relevant to features in that version go in as 4.14.1, 4.14.2 and so on.

This should give clearer picture: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/2.Process.html

Comment: patches which cause regressions are looked upon unfavorably and are quite likely to be reverted during the stabilization period. How they are doing it which tool linux use to discard this **specific changes**  before pushing changes to main stream.

Comment: There's a heirarchy of maintainers who decide which patches to revert. So selecting specific changes is done by humans. 'Lifecycle of a patch' covers that aspect in detail.

Comment: But I'm wondering how much time this manual work will take because there is >10K changeset.

Comment: Firstly workload is distributed across whole community. So users can report bugs in new patches. Additionally, the hierarchy of maintainers form a chain of trust where a patch has to be acked or reviewed by a trusted maintainer or developer which will help weed out bugs.